# Do questions about numerical analysis and software packages belong here?

Tags: discussion

I just whether is this a right place to ask about the theoretical analysis of numerical methods or the software packages pertaining to numerical analysis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, absolutely!

This line is here to satisfy the SE minimum character restriction.